tenv can't detect Terraform version
Per my understanding tenv should detect terraform version from versions.tf, but this isn't work or I did something wrong?
cat versions.tf 
terraform {
  required_version = "1.5.7"
}

But for tenv detect I have an error:
tenv tf detect -n
No version files found for Terraform, fallback to latest-allowed strategy
Scan project to find .tf files
Error: no compatible version found

I checked tofuenv and tfenv but looks like they don't support that option at all

I think what you need is a .terraform-version file with the version number in it
Example
.terraform-version content
1.7.4




